# How to count and display number of all files in any working directory?

Tags: alias, prompt

I am looking for a command to count and display the number of files in any working directory. Further I want to set alias noAf for the command. I have searched for it a lot.

I found the following:

```
ls -1|wc -l
```

But it only counts the files. So please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not 100% clear.

To count all file and folders in the current working directory your specified command should work, but I does not could the hidden files (dot-files).

To count all the files and folders (also the hidden ones) in the current working directory **AND** all the sub directories and files in them:

```
user@host:~$ find | wc -l
4318
```

To just count the file and folder (also the hidden ones) in the current working directory (**WITHOUT** sub directories):

```
user@host:~$ find -maxdepth 1 | wc -l
25
```

or:

```
user@host:~$ ls -a1 | wc -l
26
```

In the second command the folder `..` (parent directory) is also counted.

**Edit:**

To display the file names too, type:

```
ls -1a | nl
user2@host:~$ ls -1a | nl
     1  .
     2  ..
     3  .bash_logout
     4  .bashrc
     5  examples.desktop
     6  .profile
```

Comment: But how to display the file names too including the hidden ones.

Comment: @Narwen see my edit^^